# Unable to get Access Token for PowerBI Embed

Tags: asp.net-core, powerbi, access-token, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed the Power BI application to Angular Client. And have already done following stuff.

Created a Power BI report and deployed to a work Space using PowerBI pro license.
Able to get the reportID and GroupId from URL.

Registered the APP in PowerBI app and in Azure AD, Provided the necessary permissions in the Azure AD

[image]

And to get the access token added following code:

[image]

And the app settings used like this:

[image]

However with the right username and password with what I have registered the Azure AD I am not getting the token.

[image]

Even though the API returned OK success I am getting this as response. I am not sure what I am missing here. I am using .net Core Application.

Comment: I'm not an Angular developer, but I think the authentication should be done using a library like this: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token" (Token URL) instead of 
    "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize"  (Authority URL).

Update the URL in the following patch of code.

[image]

Refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request) for more information.